# How to set a stoploss in vectorbt based on the number of ticks or price per contract

Tags: python, python-3.x, vectorbt

There's an options to add `tp_stop` or `sl_stop` on `vbt.Portfolio.from_signals` which is percent based.

> sl_stop : array_like of float Stop loss. Will broadcast.
>
> A percentage below/above the acquisition price for long/short
> position. Note that 0.01 = 1%.

I would like to exit based on a move of `n` price ticks or `n` dollars per contract. For example if price moves 50 ticks in against me then exit.

Answer (score 2):

I can at least point you in the right direction, though I can't answer fully.

You need to check out vectorbt's "adjust_tp_func_nb" and "adjust_sl_func_nb".

When asked about how to create a take profit rule that is more elaborate than just a static percentage, vectorbt's author has said "To add a further condition ... you need to use adjust_tp_func_nb."

Similarly, you can create custom stop loss logic with "adjust_sl_func_nb".

See [vectorbt's docs](https://vectorbt.dev/api/portfolio/base/#vectorbt.portfolio.base.Portfolio.from_signals)

And [the author's answer I mentioned](https://github.com/polakowo/vectorbt/issues/414)

Edit: I found an example that is close to your scenario, at the first link, [here](https://vectorbt.dev/api/portfolio/base/#vectorbt.portfolio.base.Portfolio.from_signals). Look for "We can implement our own stop loss or take profit, or adjust the existing one at each time step. Let's implement stepped stop-loss:"

You will see an example like:

```
>>> @njit
... def adjust_sl_func_nb(c):
...     current_profit = (c.val_price_now - c.init_price) / c.init_price
...     if current_profit >= 0.40:
...         return 0.25, True
...     elif current_profit >= 0.25:
...         return 0.15, True
...     elif current_profit >= 0.20:
...         return 0.07, True
...     return c.curr_stop, c.curr_trail

>>> close = pd.Series([10, 11, 12, 11, 10])
>>> pf = vbt.Portfolio.from_signals(close, adjust_sl_func_nb=adjust_sl_func_nb)
>>> pf.asset_flow()
0    10.0
1     0.0
2     0.0
3   -10.0  # 7% from 12 hit
4    11.0
dtype: float64
```